Supernatural Japanese horror movie about war
First things first, before downvoting me to oblivion please consider: I watched this movie a long time ago (about 13-14 years), I don't remember anything but the following scenes:

Japanese soldiers take group picture, one of them is taking photo, then the one who took photo wanted to be in picture too so he demanded to take another one as well; when other solider took photo camera, he said "Be careful, I have paid one month salary for that camera"
Ending scene, all soldiers are trapped; into the radio, they ask for help, and their voices come out from speaker; speaker starts slowly bleeding (literally blood starts slowly pouring from speaker as they ask for help)
Film is set during World War II (most probably)


"a long time ago" How long, approximately? How old would you say the movie is?

i was 5 or 6, im 19 now

Sounds like the horror movie R-Point from 2004, though it's not about WWII (and it's Korean).

On 07 January 1972, the South Korean base in Nah-Trang, Vietnam, receives a radio transmission from a missing platoon presumed dead. The high-command assigns the veteran and decorated Lieutenant Choi Tae-in to lead a squad with eight other soldiers and rescue the missing soldiers from the R-Point. When they arrive in the location, they have a shooting and defeat a Vietnamese woman with a machine gun in a trench. Later, they find a tombstone telling that one hundred years ago, Chinese killed Vietnamese, dropped them in a lake and built a temple over the place, being a sacred location to the Vietnamese. While chasing the missing soldiers, weird things happen with the rescue team.

It contains both the soldiers' group photo and the bleeding radios (see here). Here's the trailer:




Yeah, i still remember how that scene gave me chills
